# I want to list all dates and their respective data

Tags: postgresql, timestamp

I have this **access_log** table,

```
id      user_id  actionlink_id  create_time          login_status
1181    1010     1172           2017-11-02 11:42:29  1
1182    1010     1172           2017-11-02 11:50:28  0
1175    1010     1172           2017-11-02 05:50:59  1 
1177    1010     1172           2017-11-02 06:19:24  1
1183    1010     1186           2017-11-03 05:54:17  1
1185    1010     1186           2017-11-03 07:38:23  1
1184    1010     1186           2017-11-03 07:38:00  1
1189    1010     1186           2017-11-03 12:25:40  1
1188    1010     1186           2017-11-03 12:25:01  1
1187    1010     1186           2017-11-03 12:24:46  0
1186    1010     1186           2017-11-03 12:24:17  0
1190    1010     1186           2017-11-03 12:33:12  0
1193    1010     1187           2017-11-04 13:44:08  0
1194    1010     1187           2017-11-04 13:44:18  1
1195    1010     1187           2017-11-04 13:45:31  0
1196    1010     1187           2017-11-04 13:46:07  1
1197    1010     1187           2017-11-04 13:51:59  0
1198    1010     1187           2017-11-04 13:52:09  1
```

Ouput from below code

```
date        to_char
2017-11-06  00:04
```

My Query, this gives only current date values

```
select current_date,
to_char(
    coalesce (
        ((-- get the logout time for current day
        select 
            create_time 
        from 
            users.access_log 
        where 
            user_id = 1010 
        and login_status = 0 
        and date_trunc('day', create_time) = current_date 
        order by create_time desc limit 1
        ) - (-- get the login time for current day
        select 
            create_time 
        from 
            users.access_log 
        where 
            user_id = 1010 
        and login_status = 1 
        and date_trunc('day', create_time) = current_date 
        order by create_time asc limit 1
        ))
        , (select '0 minutes'::interval) )
        , 'HH24:MI')
        ;
```

But here I want list of all dates

Comment: What is the wanted output? it is very unclear what you expect

Comment: list of dates and total time spent, I'm not getting how to fetch all dates. I have written code for the current date only

Comment: have you triedc`select create_time  from access_log`? if that isn't what you want; please edit your question and provide a table that looks like the result you want

Comment: by the way, I may stop answering questions for people who haven't learned how to accept an answer. I notice you have had 5 questions so far but none are accepted yet. It takes less than a second and costs you nothing, (*in fact you get 2 points for clicking a tick icon beside the best answer*).

Comment: I want to calculate time spent according to the respective dates. whereas login_status = 1 means login & login_status = 0 means log out.

Comment: That would be useful detail to put in the question, and you have asked similar questions already so you could have at least tried on of those answers. This site EXPECTS that you at least try a query of your own, then ask for help if it isn't doing what you need it to. If my answer below was created before our comment so you ca add the wanted where clause to that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/5ba4d/6)

**PostgreSQL 9.6 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE access_log
    ("id" int, "user_id" int, "actionlink_id" int, "create_time" timestamp, "login_status" int)
;

INSERT INTO access_log
    ("id", "user_id", "actionlink_id", "create_time", "login_status")
VALUES
    (1181, 1010, 1172, '2017-11-02 11:42:29', 1),
    (1182, 1010, 1172, '2017-11-02 11:50:28', 0),
    (1175, 1010, 1172, '2017-11-02 05:50:59', 1),
    (1177, 1010, 1172, '2017-11-02 06:19:24', 1),
    (1183, 1010, 1186, '2017-11-03 05:54:17', 1),
    (1185, 1010, 1186, '2017-11-03 07:38:23', 1),
    (1184, 1010, 1186, '2017-11-03 07:38:00', 1),
    (1189, 1010, 1186, '2017-11-03 12:25:40', 1),
    (1188, 1010, 1186, '2017-11-03 12:25:01', 1),
    (1187, 1010, 1186, '2017-11-03 12:24:46', 0),
    (1186, 1010, 1186, '2017-11-03 12:24:17', 0),
    (1190, 1010, 1186, '2017-11-03 12:33:12', 0),
    (1193, 1010, 1187, '2017-11-04 13:44:08', 0),
    (1194, 1010, 1187, '2017-11-04 13:44:18', 1),
    (1195, 1010, 1187, '2017-11-04 13:45:31', 0),
    (1196, 1010, 1187, '2017-11-04 13:46:07', 1),
    (1197, 1010, 1187, '2017-11-04 13:51:59', 0),
    (1198, 1010, 1187, '2017-11-04 13:52:09', 1)
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
select
       user_id, actionlink_id, date_trunc('day',create_time) dt
     , min(case when login_status = 1 then create_time end) min_time
     , max(case when login_status = 0 then create_time end) max_time
     , max(create_time) - min(create_time) elapsed_time
from access_log
group by
    user_id, actionlink_id, date_trunc('day',create_time)
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/5ba4d/6/0)**:

```
| user_id | actionlink_id |                   dt |             min_time |             max_time |                                     elapsed_time |
|---------|---------------|----------------------|----------------------|----------------------|--------------------------------------------------|
|    1010 |          1186 | 2017-11-03T00:00:00Z | 2017-11-03T05:54:17Z | 2017-11-03T12:33:12Z | 0 years 0 mons 0 days 6 hours 38 mins 55.00 secs |
|    1010 |          1172 | 2017-11-02T00:00:00Z | 2017-11-02T05:50:59Z | 2017-11-02T11:50:28Z | 0 years 0 mons 0 days 5 hours 59 mins 29.00 secs |
|    1010 |          1187 | 2017-11-04T00:00:00Z | 2017-11-04T13:44:18Z | 2017-11-04T13:51:59Z |   0 years 0 mons 0 days 0 hours 8 mins 1.00 secs |
```

Comment: this answer was amended to include some logic on  `login_status`

Comment: Thank you so much. I want this answer only. happy for your answer.

Comment: actually, i don't have 15 reputations to vote for your answer. sorry for that